# Being disconnected from chromecast when locking iOS device

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, chromecast

I'm facing a strange behavior from the last google chromecast SDK on iOS.
Indeed when I lock the device while casting I often end up with a network error ending the current cast session.

The error is:
`Error Domain=com.google.cast.GCKError Code=17 "Network not reachable" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Network not reachable}`

The device is not disconnected during the process.
I have also set the cast option so that it should not disconnect while in background.

```
let options = GCKCastOptions(discoveryCriteria: criteria)
options.suspendSessionsWhenBackgrounded = false
```

I don't seem to be able to pinpoint what is causing this 
erratic behavior or how to avoid it.
I'm open to any suggestions on what could be the root cause of this and how to fix it.

Edit: I have reproduced this bug with the new demo app of google. This problem seems to be coming from the chromecast SDK.

Best,

Martin

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. And my app is registered to play background audio. Did you find a solution for this? Does using background tasks fix the issue?

Comment: For what it's worth, users are reporting this on ios 14: https://www.reddit.com/r/Chromecast/comments/ixh3tu/ios_14_cast_issues/